# Mysql conditional case when as column doesnt compile

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    DISPLAY_ID,
    PICKER_NAME,
    CREDIT,
    HOURLY_RATE,
    DAILY_RATE,
    WEIGHT,
    CASE
        WHEN (DeviceGroups IS NOT NULL AND WorkerGroups IS NOT NULL) THEN CONCAT(DeviceGroups,',',WorkerGroups);
        WHEN (DeviceGroups IS NULL AND WorkerGroups IS NOT NULL) THEN WorkerGroups;
        WHEN (DeviceGroups IS NOT NULL AND WorkerGroups IS NULL) THEN DeviceGroups;
        WHEN (DeviceGroups IS NULL AND WorkerGroups NOT NULL) THEN NULL;
    END as GROUPS
FROM....
```

I try to use Case When syntax with as for alians, i get this error :

> SQL query: Documentation

SELECT DISPLAY_ID, PICKER_NAME, CREDIT, HOURLY_RATE, DAILY_RATE, WEIGHT,
CASE
WHEN (

DeviceGroups IS NOT NULL
AND WorkerGroups IS NOT NULL
)
THEN CONCAT( DeviceGroups,  ',', WorkerGroups ) ;

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon :

```
SELECT 
    DISPLAY_ID,
    PICKER_NAME,
    CREDIT,
    HOURLY_RATE,
    DAILY_RATE,
    WEIGHT,
    CASE
        WHEN (DeviceGroups IS NOT NULL AND WorkerGroups IS NOT NULL) THEN CONCAT(DeviceGroups,',',WorkerGroups)
        WHEN (DeviceGroups IS NULL AND WorkerGroups IS NOT NULL) THEN WorkerGroups
        WHEN (DeviceGroups IS NOT NULL AND WorkerGroups IS NULL) THEN DeviceGroups
        WHEN (DeviceGroups IS NULL AND WorkerGroups IS NULL) THEN NULL
    END as GROUPS
FROM....
```

In standard SQL, a semicolon(;) is used to end the query .